# Will a git new merge request include reverted master commits for redeployment of branch changes?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a dev branch (dev-cj1) that had two previous commits merged to master and then deployed to production for a new app feature. The deploy was reverted via a revert from master and a redeploy to restore production to a pre-deploy state to fix a found bug. The bug has been fixed and now I am ready to deploy the now fixed original feature. However, when I look at the files that make up the new merge request, it shows only the 4 files I most recently changed rather than the other original 14 files that need to deploy again.

How do I merge the older two commits along with the bug fix commit. Should be 4 commits 14 files changed total vs 1 commit 4 files changed?

Comment: You need to revert the revert commits.

Comment: I didn't get to try what was suggested, so I don't know if it would have worked. Unfortunately, I think I have gone too far beyond my original position to be able to try it and am now trying to cherry pick from the commits I need to pull into the latest commit. So sorry for the hassle folks.

Comment: You should be able to revert at any time, though there may be conflicts. No worries. Just delete your question.

Comment: I think I'll just close the question as your suggestion seems to be something I could learn from/use in the future. Thanks!